# Android 4.0.3 Browser SVG rendering issues

Tags: android, html, mobile, web, svg

I'm working on a mobile website project and decided to use SVG for the logo to bypass image/screen pixel density issues.

The svg code renders fine in ios and in chrome on android but for some reason on my Android 4.0.3 native browser aka the 'Internet' app, it doesn't render. It takes up the space it should but nothing draws in the space.

Here's a fiddle showing my svg code and the css I have attached to it. Any ideas would be super helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/vQsa5/1/

Here is the code for my svg

```
<svg version="1.1" id="logoImg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                 width="380px" height="62px" viewBox="0 0 380 62" enable-background="accumulate" xml:space="preserve">
            <g>
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="190.0005" y1="61.7227" x2="190.0005" y2="0.0649">
                            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#632C15"/>
                            <stop  offset="0.0197" style="stop-color:#6E2B17"/>
                            <stop  offset="0.09" style="stop-color:#8F271D"/>
                            <stop  offset="0.1682" style="stop-color:#AC2322"/>
                            <stop  offset="0.2549" style="stop-color:#C42127"/>
                            <stop  offset="0.3535" style="stop-color:#D61F2A"/>
                            <stop  offset="0.4714" style="stop-color:#E31D2C"/>
                            <stop  offset="0.6276" style="stop-color:#EA1C2E"/>
                            <stop  offset="0.9755" style="stop-color:#EC1C2E"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        <path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" d="M356.526,21.217h-30.202v7.299h30.202c7.154,0.018,12.938,5.797,12.954,12.951
                            c-0.017,7.15-5.8,12.938-12.954,12.951h-30.185c-7.154-0.014-12.946-5.801-12.954-12.951V23.365
                            c0.017-8.82,7.162-15.967,15.988-15.979h26.771V0.086l-26.771-0.004c-8.076,0.004-15.188,4.115-19.368,10.359
                            c-3.896-6.215-10.782-10.352-18.66-10.355h-26.625c-12.171,0.004-22.031,9.865-22.039,22.029v19.049
                            c0,5.061,1.836,9.672,4.869,13.254h-36.071c-7.309-0.014-13.23-5.914-13.257-13.227c0,0,0-41.045,0-41.127h-7.3v6.404
                            c-4.172-3.943-9.792-6.383-15.989-6.387H148.16v7.305h26.775c8.818,0.021,15.972,7.158,15.989,15.984v18.1
                            c-0.018,7.146-5.801,12.934-12.955,12.947h-30.185c-7.154-0.014-12.946-5.801-12.959-12.947v-0.004h0.004v-0.025
                            c0.025-7.141,5.805-12.908,12.955-12.926h30.202v-7.299h-30.202c-4.935,0-9.447,1.762-12.959,4.684v-2.525
                            c0-12.859-10.425-23.285-23.285-23.289H89.873c-8.257,0-15.489,4.305-19.622,10.783C66.113,4.391,58.882,0.086,50.625,0.082
                            H23.857v7.305h26.767c8.727,0.012,15.795,6.994,15.972,15.691c0,0.096-0.018,0.193-0.018,0.297l0.034,18.092
                            c-0.013,7.15-5.805,12.938-12.95,12.951H23.474c-7.154-0.014-12.941-5.801-12.95-12.951c0.009-7.154,5.796-12.934,12.95-12.951
                            H53.68v-7.299H23.474c-11.183,0-20.255,9.059-20.255,20.25c0,11.188,9.072,20.25,20.255,20.256h30.189
                            c11.183-0.006,20.25-9.068,20.255-20.256l-0.004-18.102c0-0.076-0.013-0.158-0.013-0.24c0.146-8.709,7.228-15.717,15.972-15.738
                            h21.668c8.826,0.021,15.967,7.158,15.985,15.988v18.092l0,0v0.004c0,11.184,9.067,20.246,20.259,20.252h30.185
                            c6.912-0.006,13.023-3.479,16.678-8.779c3.715,5.305,9.869,8.773,16.833,8.779h81.349c6.973,0,13.118-3.475,16.833-8.779
                            c3.655,5.301,9.758,8.773,16.679,8.779h30.185c11.188-0.006,20.255-9.068,20.255-20.256
                            C376.781,30.275,367.715,21.217,356.526,21.217z M292.83,54.412h-29.59c-7.309-0.008-13.239-5.926-13.248-13.248V22.115
                            c0.009-8.131,6.594-14.707,14.73-14.729h26.625c8.146,0.021,14.722,6.598,14.739,14.729v19.049
                            C306.069,48.486,300.147,54.404,292.83,54.412z"/>
                        <g>
                            <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="361.9355" y1="2.9004" x2="361.9355" y2="0.0977">
                                <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#632C15"/>
                                <stop  offset="0.0197" style="stop-color:#6E2B17"/>
                                <stop  offset="0.09" style="stop-color:#8F271D"/>
                                <stop  offset="0.1682" style="stop-color:#AC2322"/>
                                <stop  offset="0.2549" style="stop-color:#C42127"/>
                                <stop  offset="0.3535" style="stop-color:#D61F2A"/>
                                <stop  offset="0.4714" style="stop-color:#E31D2C"/>
                                <stop  offset="0.6276" style="stop-color:#EA1C2E"/>
                                <stop  offset="0.9755" style="stop-color:#EC1C2E"/>
                            </linearGradient>
                            <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" d="M357.794,0.75h1.438v2.129h0.646V0.75h1.414V0.098h-3.499V0.75z M366.077,2.9V1.275
                                c0-0.65-0.526-1.172-1.173-1.178h-2.017c-0.646,0.006-1.173,0.527-1.173,1.178V2.9h0.646V1.275c0-0.293,0.233-0.531,0.526-0.531
                                h0.672v2.148h0.646V0.744h0.698c0.293,0,0.526,0.238,0.526,0.531V2.9H366.077z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
            </svg>
```

and the css I have with it

```
#logoImg{
width: 115px;
height: 50px;
-webkit-transform-origin-x: 50%;
-webkit-transform-origin-y: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Edit: I had to embed it as an <object> tag and then remove the width and height attributes out of the svg root tag in the file. This is working for me on ios android browser and chrome for android. I'm still open to better ideas though.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `object` element is the second best way to use SVG (images). Unfortunately there is the annoying height bug in Safari.

The best, or the most robust way I found so far, is to use the SVG in an image tag!

```
<img src="<path to image .svg>" alt="my SVG image">
```

You can also use a data url and include your SVG file Base64 encoded, which saves the HTTP request.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GBhUe/1/)